# how to use non static Dll functions written in c# , in Iron python?

Tags: c#, python, dll, instance, ironpython

I wrote this simple example in c# :

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;

  namespace DLLTest
  {
        public class MyDllTest
          {
                 public  int sumFunc(int a, int b)
                    {

        int sum = a + b;
        return sum;

    }

    public static string stringFunc(string a, int numT)
    {
           if (numT < 0)
            {
               string errStr = "Error! num < 0";
               return errStr;
            }
              else
             {
                 return a;
             }

         }
    }
}
```

As you can see - in the first function i'm not using "static" .
When I run in in Iron python using this code :

```
import sys
 import clr
clr.addReferenceToFileAndPath(...path do dll...)

from DLLTest import *
 res = MyDllTest.sumFunc(....HERE MY PROBLEM IS...)
```

when I pass 2 args - I get this error :

```
>>> res = MyDllTest.sumFunc(4,5)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sumFunc() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

As I understand it asks for the fisrt argument to be from type "MyDllTest"
but when trying to write : `a = new MyDllTest` I get an error.

what should I do?
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sumFunc` is an instance method, so you first need to create an instance of the class to be able to call the method.

```
import clr
clr.addReferenceToFileAndPath(...path do dll...)

from DLLTest import MyDllTest

test = MyDllTest()
test.sumFunc(33, 44)
```

C# non-static methods could be called only on the instance of the class and static methods can be called on the class itself.

[Static and instance methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: got it! I was sure I need to use "new MyDllTest" but now I see that "new" is not needed here... thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Yes, `new` doesn't exist in Python, just use the classes as normal Python classes.